# "FormatException was unhandled by user code" Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I click submit button without typing a `number in my text box`,

I get error message

> FormatException was unhandled by user code, Input string was not in a
>   correct format.

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int section = Convert.ToInt32(lstSectionNumber.SelectedValue);
    double ticketQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfTickets.Text);
}
```

I understand that I can validate the text box so I have to type in the number, but can anyone guide me to the correct way of fixing this?

Thank you, I've only been using C# for a week.

Comment: Look at [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hbw267h(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using int.TryParse method.

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int section = 0; //or your default value
        double ticketQuantity = 0d; //Or your default value

        int.TryParse(lstSectionNumber.SelectedValue, out section);
        double.TryParse(txtNumberOfTickets.Text, out ticketQuantity);

    }
```

Comment: would you be able to help me with adding that to my code? I've tried several things but it kept giving me an error

Comment: Done. It would be nice if you could mark any of the answers as an accepted answer @user3236592

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int section;

            int.TryParse(lstSectionNumber.SelectedItem.ToString(),out section);
            MessageBox.Show(section.ToString());


        }
```

Comment: This is how i have my code but it still gives me an error.            int section;
int.TryParse(lstSectionNumber.SelectedValue.ToString(), out section);
double ticketQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfTickets.Text);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to throw an exception for this try this one:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int section = Convert.ToInt32(lstSectionNumber.SelectedValue);
        double ticketQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfTickets.Text);
    }

    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        // put an error message.
    }
}
```

If the user enters a non-numeric value, it will throw an exception instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the return boolean in `TryParse` like so:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int section = Convert.ToInt32(lstSectionNumber.SelectedValue);

    double ticketQuantity;
    if(!int.TryParse(txtNumberOfTickets.Text, out section))
    {
        //Some error handling here...like MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid ticket quanity");
    }

    //Do you regular logic here...
}
```

On a side note: why is your `ticketQuantity` a double but you're converting to an int? Also note that, depending on what `1stSectionNumber` is using as a source, you could have a similar conversion error there. When handling user input, it's usually a good idea to wrap in a Try-Catch so that your app doesn't crash. Even MessageBox with the error is usually better than a crash to desktop.

Comment: I didn't realize this was an asp.net application. You'd obviously want some validation on the client side, but still use TryParse as another line of defense against bad input.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <tr>
        <td style="width:30%; text-align:right;">
              <asp:Label ID="lbltext" runat="server">Text Box</asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td style="width:30%; text-align:left;">
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtbox1" runat="server" 
                       ValidationGroup="Sample" 
                       Width="100%" >
          </asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
                                            runat="server"
                                            ControlToValidate="txtbox1" 
                                            Display="Dynamic"
                                            ErrorMessage="Only Numbers"
                                            ForeColor="Red"
                                            ValidationExpression="^[0-9]*$">
           </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
                                        runat="server"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtbox1" 
                                        Display="Dynamic"
                                        ErrorMessage="Field cannot be left blank" 
                                        ForeColor="Red">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         </td>
    </tr>
```

Add **RegularExpression** to **validate** the **textbox** gets **only numbers** in the textbox and also add **required field** to the textbox so that it **does not allows empty string** to be passed.

By this way you achieve this

if you dont want to use RegularExpression and RequiredField Validators you can change your code like below

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int section;
        int.TryParse(ddl1.SelectedValue, out section);
        double ticketQuantity;
        double.TryParse(txtbox1.Text, out ticketQuantity);

    }
```

By this you will be getting **`Section`** value as **`0`** and **`ticketQuantity`** as **`0.0`**

Answer (score 0):

```
int section ;
int.TryParse(lstSectionNumber.SelectedValue,out section);
double ticketQuantity;
double.TryParse(txtNumberOfTickets.Text,out ticketQuantity);
```

In case of error you will get 0 or 0.0 without throwing error.